# Google Ad Manager get custom key value showing as "unknown" in reports

Tags: google-dfp, google-ad-manager

We are trying to use the key value feature in google ad manager in a report,

```
// example
var targetingData = [];
targetingData['utm_campaign'] = new Date().getTime();
targetingData['utm_term'] = new Date().getTime();
        googletag.defineSlot('/account-id/Minf-3', [300, 100], 'div-gpt-ad-1576162076591-0')
            .addService(googletag.pubads()).setTargeting('utm_term', targetingData['utm_term'])
            .setTargeting('utm_campaign', targetingData['utm_campaign']);

        googletag.pubads().setTargeting('utm_term', targetingData['utm_term'])
            .setTargeting('utm_campaign', targetingData['utm_campaign']);
```

Then we are generating a report with key values, but the values are all 
 shown as unknown.
when we check it in the page 
that key value is set correctly we are calling to **getTargeting** method, and we always get the correct value:

```
googletag.pubads().getTargeting('utm_term');
googletag.pubads().getTargeting('utm_campaign');
```

Is there something we are missing here?

How do we generate a report that can show us the value of the "key values" along with the impressions and clicks?

- We manage to see values only when we set them as predefined, so we having this issue only when we set the values dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

The targeting values should be strings, you're passing numbers.
Try converting the timestamp into a string first, for example:

```
googletag.pubads().setTargeting('utm_term', new Date().getTime() + '')
```

Comment: I tried with string as well, and they are defined as dynamic means you can set every value there.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make sure your key/values are set up as "custom dimensions" for your reports to be able to pull values. It has to be done through Ad Manage UI. According to [this](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7352444?hl=en) support page :

1. Click Inventory and then Key-values.
2. Click the name of a key to be used in Ad Manager reports
3. Under "Report on values," select Include values in reporting
4. Click Save

On the "Key-values" page, the value in the "Reportable" column will change to "On."

Then you should be able to get the values of the keys in the report.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try and let you know if this is what we missed.

Comment: once you set the key values as custom dimensions you see Reportable = "Custom dimension"

Comment: did it work ? were you able to get values in report ?

Comment: it is possible. Look a these screeshots (dynamic key, and data from report).See here : https://imgur.com/a/o3KimMs

Comment: in the screenshot you sent it is not reflect values that are changed, it is predefined values.